# How to get the namespace object in NodeJS module？

Tags: node.js, namespaces

If I define a function, let's say

```
function help() {  
   console.log('Help');
}
```

for some reasons, I cannot get the function object directly, all I got is the function name,
in browser, it would not bother at all, I can get function `Help` by `window['help']`
**BUT** in NodeJS module, as I know, all objects are defined in the anomynous namespace,
except for those objects which defined in `global`/`exports`/`module.exports`.
So how could I get the function `Help` under the circumstance(without changing function `Help` definition to `global`/`exports`/`module.exports`)?

Answer (score 0):

@naomik
Actually the function Help is just a private function, I don't want to expose it...
now, I construct an object `helpFuncs` to hold function `Help`.

```
var funcName = 'Help';  
var helpFuncs = {  
  Help: function() {}   
};
```

So I can get the function object by helpFuncs[funcName].
*btw, OMG, the format sucks, and github flavored markdown is really much easier to use.*